# A screenshot that links to a page from PDF

Tags: org-mode, org-link, inline-image

Suppose that I have a link to a screenshot of part of a PDF page in an `org` buffer. How can I change the behavior of the link so that, when the displayed inline image is clicked, instead of opening the image file, the PDF file from which the screenshot was taken would be opened?

One possible direction I thought about was to define my own link type, which would encode both the image's and the PDF's file names and the page number in the PDF, something like `pdfscreenshot:image-file-name--pdf-file-name--page-number`. I would then be able to define its `:follow` action to open the required page of the PDF. However, how will I cause this link to behave as an image link, such as being displayed when `org-startup-with-inline-images` is set?